# compare int arrays for 'similarity' - more accurate than weighted average?

Tags: arrays, similarity

say there is a number of arrays with length 12, containing signed integers in a range of roughly ±100, how can i compare the 'signature' or 'harmonic content' of these arrays to each other, in a way that is more accurate than a simple weighted average?

Would i have to look into neural networks (if this even would be suitable, i don't know tbh) or is there a more straightforward way?

EDIT:

on a graph, imagine the index on the x-axis and the value on the y-axis. two arrays would be very similar if the shape of the graphs would be similar after normalization.

i find it hard to find the right words for this problem.

Comment: Define "more accurate". "Mean distance" is as good as anything else when you have no clue what sort of "similarity" you're talking about.

Comment: Are you trying to do pitch detection?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/echo-nest-java-api/ i'm using this API for musical analysis and try to process the timbre information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays could be treated as signals, hence you should try to do a [scaled cross correlation](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/miscellaneous/correlate/) between the two signals, or extract frequency domain info and compare their spectrum ( [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) of both signals ).